# What happens if view function calls function that is neither 'view' nor 'pure'?

Tags: solidity, view, pure

currently view is not enforced. Calling a function that is neither 'view' nor 'pure' from within a function that is causes a warning, but compiles.

My question is what is the result from externally calling such a function, and is the result well defined? Does it return the correct result but simply not change state?

for example:

```
contract Test {
    uint counter = 0;
    function A() public returns (uint256) {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    function B() public view returns (uint256) {
        return A();
    }
}
```

What happens if I call B() externally? does it for sure return the current counter without consuming gas, just without making a state change to the contract?

Answer (score 6):

Functions can be invoked in two different ways:

1. Via a *transaction*, which is broadcast to the network and changes blockchain state.
2. Via a *call*, which is performed locally on a single Ethereum network and does not change any blockchain state.

It's actually up to the client to decide which to do, but if a function is marked `view`, the default behavior of most clients (e.g. Remix, web3.js, etc.) is to use a *call*. That basically means running the transaction but not recording any state changes.

So in the above case, if you call `B()`, it will in effect give you back the value `counter + 1`. (During execution, it will increment the counter, but that change will simply be discarded.)

That said, you *could* invoke `B()` via a *transaction*, in which case the `counter` would truly be incremented in a persistent way. In essence, `view` is a hint to clients that they should use a call rather than a transaction.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I see the returned value would be the same in both cases. Would the second case - aside from also changing state - be more reliable in any way?

Comment: Transactions don't actually have return values, so you would have a tough time getting back the new `counter` value if you used a  transaction. It's hard to say if a transaction is more "reliable" without some definition of what you mean.